# BitmapFactory.decodeResource is returning 0 for outHeight & outWidth with inJustDecodeBounds = true

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

I am following the android developer tutorials on displaying bitmap's efficiently and I'm trying to read a bitmap's dimensions and type.

This is the code I have for reading the bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
    imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

My results for imageHeight, imageWidth both seem to be 0 and the imageType is null.

The image is of bitmap format.

My onCreate method is

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage);
    Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bmp_login_screen);
    imgView.setImageDrawable(draw);



    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

    ReadBitmapDimen dimensions = new ReadBitmapDimen(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText(" Dimensions for userlogin image: outHeight = " + String.valueOf(dimensions.imageHeight));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line - `image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);`

to

```
image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.bmp_login_screen, options);
```

Comment: Yes, that's great! Thanks so much, now I can progress :D

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.myimage` is not a valid drawable resource. Should be `R.drawable.something`.